# Batch renaming files into sub directories

Tags: zsh

I have files as follows:

```
assets/
├─ icon_1.png
├─ icon_1@2x.png
├─ icon_1@3x.png
├─ icon_2.png
├─ icon_2@2x.png
├─ icon_2@3x.png
```

and I want to change it to this format:

```
assets/
├─ icon_1/
│  ├─ 3.0x/
│  │  ├─ icon_1.png
│  ├─ 2.0x/
│  │  ├─ icon_1.png
│  ├─ icon_1.png
├─ icon_2/
│  ├─ 3.0x/
│  │  ├─ icon_2.png
│  ├─ 2.0x/
│  │  ├─ icon_2.png
```

I am trying to use `zmv` commands such as

```
zmv '(*).png' $1/'$1.png'
```

or

```
zmv '(*).png' '$1/$1.png'
```

to get a feel of how it works. However, it tells me that I do not have the right directories. Is there a way to create directories dynamically from the file names?

Comment: Like `mv`, `zmv` can't make directories on the fly by itself. However zmv has the option `-p PROG` (see _man zshcontrib_). With this option, instead of moving the file, your program PROG will be invoked with the two aguments (source and destination), and you could inside PROG create the directory which you need.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't really able to find a way to parametrize the suffixes and create the directories dynamically, however I did find a solution for my specific case of the problem.

I ran the following commands on `zsh`:

```bash
for file in *@3x.png
do
dirname="${file%@3x.png}" #this truncates the @3x.png from 'icon_1@3x.png' and so on
mkdir "$dirname"
mkdir "$dirname/2.0x"
mkdir "$dirname/3.0x"
done
```

This creates the folder structures that I want. Now I only have to move the files from `./` to the desired directories as follows:

```bash
zmv '(*)@3x.png' '$1/3.0x/$1.png'
zmv '(*)@2x.png' '$1/2.0x/$1.png'
zmv '(*).png' '$1/$1.png'
```

I move the ones with `@3x`, `@2x` suffixes first so they don't get selected by the `(*).png` selector.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `zmv`, but you may need a somewhat complicated pattern. This will move the files if the destination directories exist:

```
zmv -n '(icon_<->)(*).png' '${1:r}/${${2#@}%x}${2:+.0x}/$1.png'
```

The -n (no-execute) option is for testing - remove it to actually move the files. The extended glob pattern `<->` matches any number; it lets us split the source pattern into two pieces. The destination pattern uses several `zsh` [parameter expansions](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) to build the path, with repeated forward slashes being treated like a single slash for the `icon_1` and `icon_2` directories.

---

Out-of-the box, `zmv` will not create directories, but it will accept a custom command that can call `mkdir`:

```
mkdir_mv () {
  mkdir -p -- $3:h
  mv -- $2 $3
}
zmv -n -p mkdir_mv '(icon_<->)(*).png' '${1:r}/${${2#@}%x}${2:+.0x}/$1.png'
```

The `mkdir_mv` code is from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59159/432774).